# When using Beam IO ReadFromPubSub module, can you pull messages with attributes in Python? It's unclear if its supported

Tags: python, google-cloud-pubsub, apache-beam-io

Trying to pull messages with attributes stored in PubSub into a Beam pipeline. I'm wondering if support has been added for Python and that's why I'm unable to read them. I see that it exists in Java.

```
pipeline_options = PipelineOptions()
pipeline_options.view_as(StandardOptions).streaming = True

pipeline = beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options)
messages = (pipeline | beam.io.ReadFromPubSub(subscription=subscription_name).with_output_types(bytes))

def printattr(element):
    print(element.attributes)


lines = messages | 'printattr' >> beam.Map(printattr)

result = pipeline.run()
result.wait_until_finish()
```

Expected to be able to list the attributes- data:

```
b'Message number 1109'
-     attributes: {
-       "_comments": "nan",
-       "_direction": "SE",
-       "_fromst": "Harlem",
-       "_last_updt": "2019-03-20 21:11:02.0",
-       "_length": "0.56",
-       "_lif_lat": "41.9809967484",
-       "_lit_lat": "41.9787314076",
-       "_lit_lon": "-87.7964600566",
-       "_strheading": "W",
-       "_tost": "Oak Park",
```

, but I can only seem to access information stored in the data field- not the attributes.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After reviewing the documentation: https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/2.11.0/apache_beam.io.gcp.pubsub.html, I was able to see an additional argument to pass in to ReadFromPubSub.

The 'with_attributes=True' needed to be set, otherwise, you just get the data fields.

Hopefully this helps someone else who may get stuck or just be tired :)

Comment: I too was struggling with this error for a day and then I found this post. Thanks!

Comment: Wow!  The default is to _not_ provide the metadata!  Google loves optimizing for the computer, never for the human programming the computer...